# Cmake ошибка линковки libpq undefined reference

Tags: postgresql, gcc, cmake, makefile

Не получается слинковать библиотеку PostgreSQL libpq.a
Вот СMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(MiningSimulatorGameServer)


add_definitions("-std=c++11 -lpq")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS date_time atomic system thread chrono regex signals)
if(Boost_FOUND)
message(STATUS "include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "lib: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})



endif()

find_package(Protobuf)
if(Protobuf_FOUND)
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  message(STATUS "include: ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "lib: ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}")


endif()
set(PostgresSQL_LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.a)

set(PosgresSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../usr/include/postgresql)
include_directories(${PosgresSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(TinyFormat_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../ThirdParty/TinyFormat/)
include_directories("${TinyFormat_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "libpq ${PostgresSQL_LIBRARIES})
message(STATUS "pq ${PosgresSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(HEADER_FILES 

${TinyFormat_DIRS}/tinyformat.h
)

set(SOURCE_FILES 
Json.c

extension.c
)

file(GLOB ${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB ${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS "*.h")
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_SOURCES "*.pb.cc")
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_HEADERS "*.pb.h")
file(GLOB ${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_LIST ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_LIST} 
${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_HEADERS} ${PROTOBUF_HEADERS} ${PROTOBUF_SOURCES})

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" ${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCE_LIST} 
${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} ${PostgresSQL_LIBRARIES} )
```

Кусок вывода в консоли

```
...
[100%] Linking CXX executable MiningSimulatorGameServer
../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.a(fe-connect.o): In function `parseServiceFile':
(.text+0xbe2): undefined reference to `ldap_init' ...
```

Есть подозрение, что флаг -lpq(который в add_definitions) игнорируется. Например в Code::Blocks линкует.

```
g++ -o
  -lpq -lpthread  ../../../../../usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.a ../../../../../usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.a  ../../../../../usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a ../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.a
```

Полный вывод: [пастбин](https://pastebin.com/QKzuBcCG)

Comment: А почему не сделать просто find_package (PostgreSQL) вместо ручной установки переменных? И если линкуешься со статической либой (есть какие-то причины?), то надо все её зависимости указывать...

Comment: -- Could NOT find PostgreSQL (missing:  PostgreSQL_TYPE_INCLUDE_DIR) (found version "9.5.10")

Comment: Решил проблему установкой apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-all

Answer (score 1):

В `target_link_libraries` передавать нужно не полный путь а только имя библиотеки. А что бы `cmake` знал где искать эту либу, нужно вызвать команду `link_directories`:

```
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} pq)
```

PS. Можно зайти в директорию где `cmake` собирает проект, там лежит папка `CMakeFiles/"ИмяЦели.dir"`, там лежит файл `link.txt`, в котором можно посмотреть какие параметры передаются линковщику.